# Windows 7 - make text and other items larger or smaller

Tags: windows-7

So I recently selected to make my stuff larger and I notice that some applications' dialogs seem to cut off[image]

In my example above the bottom is being cut off and I cannot resize the window. Is there something I need to do to scale this properly or is it an application issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's [an application issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx) (and [quite normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075802/creating-a-dpi-aware-application), unfortunately).  The application was not programmed with handling text sizes/DPIs above 100% in mind.

Perhaps check out this other SU questions for some more info and ideas to try: [What is the downside to Windows XP style DPI scaling in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/134986/what-is-the-downside-to-windows-xp-style-dpi-scaling-in-windows-7)

Comment: I'm guessing WPF solves these issues automatically?